# yii captcha doesn't show in views

Tags: yii

i'm trying to show a captcha on my register page, but for some reason it won't show. I'm using the [YiiSkeletonApp](http://travisstroud.co.uk/)

in my view

```
   echo $form->captchaRow($model,'verify',array('class' => 'input-block-level',
            'hint'=>'<i class="muted">Letters are not case-sensitive.</i>',
        ));
```

in my **models/user.php** i have this

```
public function rules() {
return array(
array('verify', 'captcha', 'allowEmpty' => !CCaptcha::checkRequirements(), 'on' => 'register, forgotPassword'),
);
```

and my **controllers/UserController.php**

```
public function accessRules() {
        return array(
            // Actions: index, create, update, password, newPassword, forgotPassword, delete
            array('allow',
                'actions' => array('captcha', 'create', 'forgotPassword', 'newPassword'),
                'expression' => 'app()->user->isGuest()',
            ),
            array('allow',
                'actions' => array('password', 'update'),
                'users' => array('@'),
            ),
            array('allow',
                'actions' => array('index', 'create', 'register', 'delete'),
                'expression' => 'app()->user->isAdmin()',
            ),
            array('deny',
                'users' => array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }
```

Comment: nevermind, reinstalled yiiskeleton and it worked :\

Answer (score 1):

`CCaptcha` requires the [gd extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) to be installed. If it isn't there, the captcha won't show up.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, define it in the action :

```
public function actions()
    {
        return array(
            // captcha action renders the CAPTCHA image displayed on the contact page
            'captcha'=>array(
                'class'=>'CCaptchaAction',
                'backColor'=>0xFFFFFF,
            ),

        );
    }
```

It should work now.